# Creating Envoy http ExtAuthz service - proto files generation

Tags: customization, envoyproxy

I'm trying to implement a Java service that implements Envoy `type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ext_authz.v3.ExtAuthz`.

As a first step, I need to generate java code from the Envoy [proto contracts](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/f3c6c6d250b2387121e113f3ae5c47b81312e05a/api/envoy/extensions/filters/http/ext_authz/v3/ext_authz.proto).

Is there a standalone method to generate the proto files or a jar with the contracts already generated I can use? We use Gradle as our main build engine.

Also which gRPC service do I need to implement?

Thanks,
Amos

Answer (score 0):

You can use [protobuf-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin) to generate java code for your protos.

The proto is not a gRPC service and you don't need a grpc service for this.